# How to wrap keras models for scikit-learn stacking ensemble usages

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I have a list of keras models already trained. I want to use them with StackingClassifier in scikit learn. Due to the fact that keras doesn't have predict_proba method I created a wrapper.

If use my models wrapped for VotingClassifier with soft and hard methods, it works.

But when I use stacking models, after first run, it shows me this error. I didn't found anything about it.

```
class KerasWrapperWithEncoder(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self, keras_model, classes_):
        self.keras_model = keras_model
        self.encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False)
        # L'encoder OneHotEncoder est passé ici
        self.classes_ = classes_  # Définit les classes disponibles

    def fit(self, X, y):
        # Models are fitted dont fit again
        y_reshaped = y.reshape(-1, 1)
        self.encoder.fit(y_reshaped)
        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        # Utilise les modèles entraînés pour faire des prédictions
        predictions = self.keras_model.predict(X)
        np_argmax = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
        print(predictions)
        print(np_argmax)
        return np_argmax

    def predict_proba(self, X):
        # Retourne les probabilités des classes pour les modèles de classification
        probabilities = self.keras_model.predict(X)
        print("Shape of probabilities:", probabilities.shape)  # Debug
        return probabilities


keras_wrapped_models_with_encoder = [
    (name.replace(' ', '_').replace('__', '_'), KerasWrapperWithEncoder(model, _target_classes_))
    for name, model in keras_models.items()
]

voting_clf = VotingClassifier(
         estimators=all_estimators,
         voting='soft', 
         n_jobs=3,  
         verbose=True)
voting_clf .fit(X_train, y_train) # works perfectly 

cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
keras_stacking_models_current_year = StackingClassifier(
    estimators=all_estimators,
    final_estimator=LogisticRegression(),
    cv=cv,
    verbose=3,
    # n_jobs=2
)


keras_stacking_models_current_year.fit(X_train, y_train) # throws error
```

```
======================================stacking_models_all_models=============================
12105/12105 [==============================] - 25s 2ms/step
Shape of probabilities: (387348, 3)
Number of classes in training fold (1) does not match total number of classes (3). Results may not be appropriate for your use case. To fix this, use a cross-validation technique resulting in properly stratified folds
_enforce_prediction_order(classes, predictions, n_classes, method)
   1457             dtype=predictions.dtype,
   1458         )
-> 1459         predictions_for_all_classes[:, classes] = predictions
   1460         predictions = predictions_for_all_classes
   1461     return predictions

ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (387348,3) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (387348,1,3)
```

Comment: Does it also error when you use `stacking_method='predict'`? Please include the full stack trace for the original error.

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in _enforce_prediction_order(classes, predictions, n_classes, method)
   1457             dtype=predictions.dtype,
   1458         )
-> 1459         predictions_for_all_classes[:, classes] = predictions
   1460         predictions = predictions_for_all_classes
   1461     return predictions

ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (387348,3) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (387348,1,3)

Comment: If you set `stacking_method='predict'` does it error? At the moment it uses `predict_proba` by default.

Comment: Yes thank a lot, it'seems working. The stacking model is not failing after predicting first model. I will let you know if it's very working after the run. Thanks

Comment: No problem, glad we found something. It suggests an issue with `predict_proba`, but not sure what it is (the dimensions you're printing out look correct).

Comment: Yes It seems very weird. VotingClassifier use predict_proba with soft vote , how the same method doesn't work with StackingClassifier

Comment: I have posted an answer below with a custom stacking classifier - it might help with figuring out what the problem is. By the way, `all_estimators` is always a `list` of estimators, right? i.e. not just a single estimator.

Comment: Also, the way `estimators=` must be supplied to sklearn's `StackingClassifier` is like this: `estimators=[('Estimator0Name', estimator0), ('Estimator1Name', estimator1), ...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my case, changing stacking_method to 'predict' works

Answer (score 1):

From the comments we haven't been able to ascertain what the cause is. Below is a simple implementation of a stacking classifier which you might be able to use instead (or if the same error occurs, perhaps you can debug the issue more easily). I've included some test data at the end to show it working.

The implementation uses CV to get out-of-sample probabilities/decision values/predictions from each estimator. Those outputs are concatenated and used to train the final estimator. Finally, the base estimators are refitted on the entire training set. When it comes to prediction, the outputs from each base estimator are obtained and concatenated. They are fed into the blender to get the final output.

Simple stacking classifier class:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import (
    BaseEstimator,
    ClassifierMixin,
    check_X_y,
    check_array,
    clone
)
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold, cross_val_predict
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

class SimpleStackingClassifier(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    """
    SimpleStackingClassifier
    
    estimators:      a list of estimators
    final_estimator: None by default will use LogisticRegression()
    cv:              None by default will use StratifiedKFold()
    stack_method:    None by default will use predict_proba(), decision_function() or
                       predict() depending on which is available across all base estimators
    n_jobs, verbose: these are passed internally to cross_val_predict()
    random_state: None by default, supplied to internal attributes
    """
    def __init__(
        self, estimators, final_estimator=None,
        cv=None, stack_method='auto', n_jobs=1, verbose=0, random_state=None
    ):
        self.estimators = estimators
        self.final_estimator = final_estimator
        self.cv = cv
        self.stack_method = stack_method
        self.n_jobs = n_jobs
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.random_state = random_state
    
    #Find a stacking method that all base estimators have in common
    def find_common_stack_method(self, estimators):
        stack_methods = ['predict_proba', 'decision_function', 'predict']
        
        for stack_method in stack_methods:
            if all([hasattr(estimator, stack_method) for estimator in estimators]):
                break
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError(
                f'Estimators must all implement one of {stack_methods}'
            )
        return stack_method
            
    def fit(self, X, y):
        #
        # Input checks
        #
        X, y = check_X_y(X, y)
        self.n_features_in_ = X.shape[1]
        
        if hasattr(X, 'columns'):
            self.feature_names_in_ = np.array(
                X.columns, dtype=object
            )
        
        if not self.final_estimator:
            self.final_estimator = LogisticRegression(random_state=self.random_state)
        if not self.cv:
            self.cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=self.random_state)
        
        #Determine a common stack method
        if self.stack_method == 'auto':
            self.stack_method_ = self.find_common_stack_method(self.estimators)
        else:
            self.stack_method_ = self.stack_method

        #Get out-of-sample predictions per estimator
        oos_predictions_list = []
        for estimator in self.estimators:
            oos_predictions = cross_val_predict(
                estimator, X, y,
                cv=self.cv,
                method=self.stack_method_,
                n_jobs=self.n_jobs,
                verbose=self.verbose,
            )
            oos_predictions_list.append(
                oos_predictions.reshape(-1, oos_predictions.ndim)
            )
        
        #[est0[:, 0] est0[:, 1]  est1[:, 0] est1[:, 1] ...]
        # could optionally discard a column when classes dim > 1
        # oos_predictions_list = [oos_preds[:, 1:] if oos_preds.ndim >= 2 else oos_preds
        #                         for oos_preds in oos_predictions_list]
        oos_predictions_arr = np.concatenate(oos_predictions_list, axis=1)
        self.base_estimators_oos_predictions_ = oos_predictions_arr
        
        #Fit blender on the concatenated out-of-sample predictions
        self.final_estimator_ = clone(self.final_estimator).fit(oos_predictions_arr, y)
        
        #Fit base estimators on all training data
        self.estimators_ = [clone(estimator).fit(X, y)
                            for estimator in self.estimators]
        
        return self
    
    def _predict(self, X, final_predict_method):
        #
        #Input checks
        #
        X = check_array(X)
        
        if hasattr(self, 'feature_names_in_') and not hasattr(X, 'columns'):
            raise Warning('Estimator was fitted with feature names, '
                          'but supplied X has no feature names attribute')
        elif hasattr(X, 'columns') and (X.columns.tolist() != self.feature_names_in_.tolist()):
            raise AttributeError('X column names are different from fitted names')
        
        #Get predictions from each estimator, and feed into blender
        base_predictions = np.column_stack(
            [getattr(estimator, self.stack_method_)(X)
            for estimator in self.estimators_]
        )
        return getattr(self.final_estimator_, final_predict_method)(base_predictions)
    
    def predict(self, X):
        return self._predict(X, final_predict_method='predict')
    
    def predict_proba(self, X):
        return self._predict(X, final_predict_method='predict_proba')
    
    def predict_log_proba(self, X):
        return self._predict(X, final_predict_method='predict_log_proba')
    
    def get_feature_names_out(self, input_features=None):
        return self.final_estimator_.get_feature_names_out(input_features)
```

Test using a classification dataset:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC

#Classification dataset
X, y = make_moons(n_samples=800, noise=0.2, random_state=0)
X = pd.DataFrame({'x0': X[:, 0], 'x1': X[:, 1]})

#View training data
X_trn, X_val, y_trn, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

plt.scatter(X_trn.iloc[:, 0], X_trn.iloc[:, 1], c=y_trn, marker='.', cmap='Set1')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(5, 3)

estimator0 = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=10, random_state=np.random.RandomState(0)).fit(X_trn, y_trn)
estimator1 = SVC(C=0.1, probability=True, random_state=np.random.RandomState(1)).fit(X_trn, y_trn)

stacked = SimpleStackingClassifier([estimator0, estimator1],
                                   stack_method='predict_proba',
                                   random_state=np.random.RandomState(0))
stacked.fit(X_trn, y_trn)

#Compare scores with and without stacking
print(
    'Train scores:\n',
    'tree:   ', '%.3f' % estimator0.score(X_trn, y_trn), '\n',
    'svc:    ', '%.3f' % estimator1.score(X_trn, y_trn), '\n',
    'stacked:', '%.3f' % stacked.score(X_trn, y_trn), '\n'
)
print(    
    'Validation scores:\n',
    'tree:   ', '%.3f' % estimator0.score(X_val, y_val), '\n',
    'svc:    ', '%.3f' % estimator1.score(X_val, y_val), '\n',
    'stacked:', '%.3f' % stacked.score(X_val, y_val), ' <----'
)
```

Results suggest that the stacked classifier generalises a bit better than the individual estimators:

```
Train scores:
 tree:    1.000 
 svc:     0.941 
 stacked: 0.980 

Validation scores:
 tree:    0.942 
 svc:     0.921 
 stacked: 0.950  <----
```